# Do Memory Pressure and Memory Used have a direct relation?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, memory-pressure

I was running something on docker and this appears on the Activity Monitor. Do Memory Pressure and Memory Used have a direct relation with each other?

[image: Memory Pressure appears green and stable but Memory Used is 7.11/8.00GB]

Answer (score 2):

Memory Pressure is the efficiency at which your Mac is utilizing its memory resources.  Used memory is exactly that: how much memory is allocated.  So, yes, they are related. Basically, how *efficiently* it’s handling those resources.

[Activity Monitor Users Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/activity-monitor/check-if-your-mac-needs-more-ram-actmntr34865/mac)

> The Memory pane displays how much memory your Mac is using, how often it is swapping memory between RAM and your startup disk, and the amount of memory provided for an app and how much of it is compressed memory.
> When you have free or unused memory, your computer performance does not necessarily improve. macOS obtains the best performance by efficiently using and managing all of your computer’s memory.

> Your computer’s memory pressure is accurately measured by examining the amount of free memory available, the swap rate, and the amount of wired and file cached memory to determine if your computer is using RAM efficiently

Comment: In other words, there is no direct relationship because pressure uses other memory parameters as well as used memory.